# JavaScript - refresh page after submit form and back tu custom url

Tags: javascript

This is my base url:
domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5

under above url I have navigation tab:

tab1 tab2 tab3  tab4

- tab1: domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5
- tab2: domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5#tab2
- tab3: domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5#tab3
- tab4: domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5#tab4

When I switch to tab2 and submit form from here I need to reload this page.

For this I use script:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("form_create_domain").onsubmit = function(){
    location.reload(true);
}
</script>
```

Then problem is  this script reload and back to first tab. How to reload and stay to tab url `domain.com/home/lesson/title_lesson/5#tab2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: try! `location.href`